# Python can't find PyPi Package in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pip, pypi

I recently published a package on PyPi called ShellScriptHandeler, everything works fine, you can download it and Visual Studio Code also shows you that it exists, but when I try to import it I get the error message: No module named ShellScriptHandeler.

```
import ShellScriptHandeler

ShellScriptHandeler.Basic.open("test.sh")
```

I have no idea why that is and therefore also no idea what kind of information to give. You can download the package with "pip install ShellScriptHandeler"

Comment: Try running `pip list` (or `pip3 list`) to see if your package is there.

Comment: That is the problem, my package is displayed but it cannot be imported

Comment: Did you install it for the correct python interpreter? Try `<python_interpreter_used_in_vscode> -m pip list | grep -i shellscript`. If it doesn't show up there, it's not installed for the correct interpreter. In general, you should use `<path_to_python_interpreter> -m pip install <package>` to have full control over which interpreter the package get installed for.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the python you installed the package in is not the same as the python in your virtual environment. Can you update the post with how exactly do you install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal take the command of `pip show ShellScriptHandeler` to check where your package has been installed.

And from the bottom-left of the VSCode to check which python interpreter you have selected. If it's not the environment you have installed the package, you can click it and select the proper one.